# Will hasOwnProperty ever return false from inside a for...in loop?

Tags: javascript

If I do this:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log("Has property: " + i);
    else console.log("Doesn't have property: " + i);
}
```

Will `obj.hasOwnProperty(i)` ever return `false`? If so, when?

Comment: only hasOwnProperty("non-existing") will return false.

Comment: When property is enumerable, but not "own" and inherited instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of using hasOwnProperty within a loop is to resolve to false when looping over inherited properties. This avoids what Douglas Crockford refers to as a "deep-dredge."

Example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty :

```
var buz = {
  fog: 'stack'
};

for (var name in buz) {
  if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    alert("this is fog (" + name + ") for sure. Value: " + buz[name]);
  }
  else {
    alert(name); // toString or something else
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give and example of this? I'm not sure what an inherited property is in javascript.

Comment: Sure, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: Good call. Should've mentioned prototypal inheritance. http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Answer (score 1):

Example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty - doesn't show when `hasOwnProperty` can return false.

Here's a test case that does show that:

```
// From some library or earlier in your code
Object.prototype.xxx = "xxx";

// Your object
var data = { member: "member" };

for (var key in data) {
    if( data.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
        alert(key); // alert("member")
    }
    else {
        alert(key); // alert("xxx")
    }
}
```